# Using lapply or loop to create multiple figures from a list of lists of matricies

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested, lapply

I have a list of lists of matrices. All lists have the same amount of matrices, all matrices have the same number of columns and all matrices in a list have the same number of rows, however, the number of rows differs between matrices of different lists. I tried to recreate a small example dataset below

```
set.seed(100)
biglist <- list(
  a=list(foo=matrix(sample(1:10,30,replace=TRUE),ncol=3 ),
         bar=matrix(sample(1:10,30,replace=TRUE),ncol=3),
         puppy=matrix(sample(1:10,30,replace=TRUE),ncol=3)
  ),
  b=list(foo=matrix(sample(1:10,24,replace=TRUE),ncol=3),
         bar=matrix(sample(1:10,24,replace=TRUE),ncol=3),
         puppy=matrix(sample(1:10,24,replace=TRUE),ncol=3)
  )
)
```

I am trying create a boxplot of each matrix, where the columns are different boxplots all on the same plot. I can do this for a single matrix, but I am having trouble applying it to the entire list of lists.

Here is the code I have written for a single boxplot

```
yoptions=c('foo','bar','puppy')
mynames=c('first','second','third')
titleoptions=c('a','b')


plotdata=biglist$a$foo
colnames(plotdata)=mynames

afoo=ggplot(melt(as.data.table(plotdata)),aes(x=variable,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+ggtitle(paste(mynames[1],titleoptions[1],sep=" "))+
  ylab(paste(yoptions[1]))
```

This gives me what I want for the foo matrix in list a. I want to now be able to apply this to each matrix in the list, changing the plotdata, and titles and labels to match the corresponding matrix in the list, and then saving it to a variable that combines the list and the matrix. This would result in the following variables, all with a different plot attached to that variable:
afoo
abar
apuppy
bfoo
bbar
bpuppy

I know it is not very r-like but the first idea I had was some sort of nested for-loop, though I am not sure how that would work in this case. I know lapply is used for lists and I've done some looking into nested lapplys (lapplies?) but am not sure how to get that to make multiple variables that correspond to my figures I want to produce.

Any advice is most appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this (two nested loops):

```
for(i in 1:length(biglist)) {

  sublist <- biglist[[i]]

  for(j in 1:length(sublist)) {

    plotdata <- sublist[[j]]
    name     <- paste(english::ordinal(j),letters[i],sep="_")

    assign(name, ggplot(melt(as.data.table(plotdata)),
      aes(x=variable,y=value))+
      geom_boxplot()+ggtitle(name)+
      ylab(names(sublist)[j]))

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I go about changing the variable to which it is saved? Right now you have each plot being saved as afoo, which would mean that the previous plot would be overwritten; is there a way to change the variable that is saved as well through this for loop?

Comment: You can use ```assign``` to name the plots and save them in the environment.